# Delete row from SOShipLine in Acumatica Framework

Tags: acumatica

Good day,

I need to delete a row from SOShipLine on Shipments screen

[screenshot of action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5iPy.png)

I am working on an extension of SOShipmentEntry and trying to do the following to remove the row

```
            PXResultset<SOShipLine> shipLines = SelectFrom<SOShipLine>.InnerJoin<SOShipment>.On<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr.IsEqual<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>
            .Where<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.View.Select(Base, shipment.ShipmentNbr);

        List<Linelevel> lineLevels = osr.Transaction.Transaction.Order.LineLevel;


        foreach (SOShipLine shipLine in shipLines)
        {
            Linelevel lineLevel = lineLevels.Find(lineNbr => lineNbr.POLineNum == shipLine.LineNbr);
            if (lineLevel != null)
            {
                shipLine.ShippedQty = lineLevel.PickedQuantity;
            } else
            {
                Base.Transactions.Cache.Delete(shipLine);
            }
        }
```

but when I get to the point where I want to delete the row it generates an exception where it asks me that the key cannot be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try working directly with the Transactions view instead of querying the data with PXSelect.

```
// This is no longer needed - retrieve from the Transactions view instead
//PXResultset<SOShipLine> shipLines = SelectFrom<SOShipLine>.InnerJoin<SOShipment>.On<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr.IsEqual<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>
//  .Where<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.View.Select(Base, shipment.ShipmentNbr);

List<Linelevel> lineLevels = osr.Transaction.Transaction.Order.LineLevel;

// Cycle through the records returned directly from the Transactions view
//foreach (SOShipLine shipLine in shipLines)
foreach (SOShipLine shipLine in Base.Transactions.Select())
{
    Linelevel lineLevel = lineLevels.Find(lineNbr => lineNbr.POLineNum == shipLine.LineNbr);
    if (lineLevel != null)
    {
        shipLine.ShippedQty = lineLevel.PickedQuantity;
    } else
    {
        // Generally speaking, work with the view instead of the cache when possible
        //Base.Transactions.Cache.Delete(shipLine);
        Base.Transactions.Delete(shipLine);
    }
}
// After your logic completes, make sure the user has to press Save or you do it for them
Base.Save.Press();
```

I typically only work directly with the cache when I'm working with some other data that isn't in a view, like pushing a reference value into a record managed elsewhere.  Even then, I prefer to create a view in the graph extension and work with that.